# Snowflake's VALIDATION_MODE='RETRUN_ERROR' is not validating the file correctly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running below command to validate the data of a sample file with VALIDATION_MODE option but i do not get the expected errors.

```
copy into users from @%users/user_account.txt.gz 
file_format=(type = 'CSV') validation_mode='RETURN_ERRORS';
```

the first 2 rows in the file are below

```
id,name,emailid,signupdate
1,user1,user1@gmail.com,13/10/2021
```

since the fist line has all character values (due to header) and in the copy into command i have not used the SKIP_HEADER and DATE_FORMAT file format options so i am expecting the command to return error information.However i get 0 records returned with a successful execution of above command.

When i use below command

```
copy into users from @%users/user_account.txt.gz 
file_format=(type = 'CSV') validation_mode='RETURN_1_ROWS';
```

i get data type error for header record.Am i not using the first command in proper way ?

Comment: Could you provide the DDL of your table?  Did any of the file load during your successful execution?

Comment: Yes i am able to load file with command copy into users from @%users/user_account.txt.gz file_format=(type='CSV' date_format='DD/MM/YYYY' skip_header=1);. table DDL is create or replace TABLE USERS (
 ID NUMBER(38,0),
 NAME VARCHAR(100),
 EMAIL VARCHAR(100),
 SIGNUP DATE
); @MikeWalton

Answer (score 3):

Revising answer...  I believe what you are running into is a combination of on_error and validation_mode that isn't working together.

```
copy into users from @%users/user_account.txt.gz 
file_format=(type = CSV) 
validation_mode=RETURN_ERRORS
on_error=CONTINUE;
```

Please try above and let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: No it does not , tried already before putting this question.

Comment: not sure what was the issue but it works now even after enclosing RETURN_ERRORS in single quotes but as per documentation we should not so marking the above as right.